# Why am I getting a nullPointerException when setting JLabel text?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel

I am just a doing a little project on my own, trying to create a bingo game. I'm wondering why I'm getting a nullpointer when trying to set the text of a JLabel. The only thing the JLabel needs to display is a random number 1-15.

```
static JLabel[] boardNumbers = new JLabel[25];
static Random r = new Random();

 public static void generateBoard() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (i < 5) {
            int n = r.nextInt(15);
            numbersUsed[i] = n;
            boardNumbers[i].setText("" + n);
        } else if (i >= 5 && i < 10) {
            //i numbers
        } else if (i >= 10 && i < 15) {
            //n numbers
        } else if (i >= 15 && i < 20) {
            //g numbers
        } else {
            //o numbers
        }
    }

}
```

The line that is giving me a nullpointer is this line `boardNumbers[i].setText("" + n);`

For the full source code you can view this: https://github.com/charlieSplittstoser/Bingo/blob/master/Bing0/src/Main.java

Comment: initialize the elements of the array before using them

Comment: When you make a new array like `new JLabel[25]`, it is empty and contains only nulls.  The first thing you should do in that `for` loop is initialize the array element with a new JLabel.

Comment: `static JLabel[] boardNumbers = new JLabel[25];` creates an array of 25 elements which are `null`, you need to fill this array with instances of `JLabel`.  Also, please, learn to deal without `static`

Comment: Eclipse was yelling at me because they were not static. Also, how do I  fill those instances? I thought thats what I was doing by adding text to it.

Comment: @Chawbee Then you have a design problem, `static` is not a good way to design your code, you need to learn a better way achieve your results. It's not that you should NEVER use `static`, but you need to learn when it's use is appropriate. Over use of `static` is one of the biggest causes for problems in the questions we see here on SO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I'm a beginner to this. I don't know a way around it yet. Also how do I fill the instances of the array?

Comment: Use a `for-loop`, loop over the array and create a new `JLabel` for each element in the array

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you very much. It is now working :) The reason everything is static in the program is because I am placing the generateBoard() method the main method (public static void main(String[] args) ) . It says anything used in the method needs to be static. Is there a different way to launch generateBoard() upon the start of the program without putting it in the main method?

Comment: Use a class instance instead and call it's methods